# cast integral type passed by reference

Tags: c++, integer

If you have an integral type t1 and a function getting a possibly smaller integral type t2 by reference, would it be problematic to call function((t2)var_t1) ?

Comment: C++ and C are different languages. I've removed the C tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be fine to cast to `t2` if and only if the function took a *const reference*, in which case the temporary produced by the cast to `t2` could be bound to it.

Since this defeats the purpose of a reference to an integral type I would assume that the reference is non-const, so the answer is: yes, it would be problematic. To be clear, it won't even compile if you cast to `t2`.

If you *want* `function` to modify only parts of the `t1` variable, use a `reinterpret_cast` on the reference/pointer. This will theoretically invoke undefined behaviour, of course.

Comment: Just remeber, that the undefinedness of that behaviour is not so theoretical on big endian platforms, where it would modify the wrong part of the variable. It's true big endian platforms are becoming rarer, but they are definitely not extinct yet.

Comment: True, but it is as undefined on Big Endian as it is on Little Endian. But the results should be predictable if the target architecture is known, that's what I meant by 'theoretical'. Of course that doesn't make it much better …

Answer (score 1):

Casting will create a temporary, and if the smaller type does NOT take by `const` *reference*, your code would NOT compile, because the tempory cannot be bound to non-const reference.

If it does take by `const` *reference*, then it would compile, but the casting might cause overflow which is the usual problem from casting bigger data type to smaller one.

Answer (score 1):

The function would have to take a `const` reference, otherwise it wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Since you also tagged the question C, in which case "by reference" would just mean using a pointer, you cannot apply the `&` operator to the result of a cast. However, you could use:

```
function((t2 [1]){ (t2)var });
```

Note that is is valid C but not C++, one of the reasons you should not mix C and C++ tags...